# Add space separator to number in input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to get an input box to display numbers with space separator. Like this:
20 000 and 20 000 000 instead of 20000 and 20 000 000

The thing is that I want this to happen as you type. So when you type a number into an input element I want this spacing to be added on the fly.

Does anyone have a good solution for this?

I'm using this function to do this on static outputs, but it doesn't work well when getting the value from a textbox,  running it through the function and then putting it back, for some reason.

```
function delimitNumber(number) {
    var delimiter = " "; 

    number = new String(number);
    var parts = number.split('.', 2);
    var decimal = parts[1];
    var i = parseInt(parts[0]);

    if(isNaN(i)) 
        return ''; 

    var minus = '';

    if (i < 0) 
        minus = '-'; 

    i = Math.abs(i);
    var n = new String(i);
    var a = [];

    while(n.length > 3) {
        var nn = n.substr(n.length-3);
        a.unshift(nn);
        n = n.substr(0,n.length-3);
    }

    if (n.length > 0) 
        a.unshift(n); 

    n = a.join(delimiter);

    if (typeof decimal === 'undefined' || decimal.length < 1)  
        number = n;
    else 
     number = n + '.' + decimal;

    number = minus + number; // Assemble the number with negative sign (empty if positive)
    return number;
}
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt? I've not searched, but number-formatting questions come up pretty regularly, so I'd be a little surprised if this question hasn't been answered multiple times already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<input type="text" id="number" />
```

JS:

```
$('#number').on("keyup", function() {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/ /g,"");
    this.value = this.value.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LLcsxr6c/

I used the *keyup* event because *keypress* or *keydown* will be triggered just before the input box is actually updated.

With jQuery 2 you can use `$('#number').on("input", function()`

Comment: Very well done.  Please add an explanation of how this works, if you're after some rep :)

Comment: This is not a good solution to the problem. Because of the value change, you always end up with the marker at the end, So it is e.g. impossible to use arrow keys to navigate back or just edit in the middle of the input.

Comment: @Anders it's a good answer as per the OP's requirement. Ask a new question if you have problems implementing something specific. For the arrow keys: http://jsfiddle.net/LLcsxr6c/100/

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that will do the string manipulation for you. Next, set up a listener on your input box to listen for a key down. That key down event should trigger your function, passing the value of your input box, and in turn setting the value to the newly spaced out string.